# Calling selfdestruct with call()

Tags: solidity

suppose we have two contract contractA, contractB.

Inside contractB , can i do something like this `contractAAddress.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("selfdestruct(address payable)", contractBAddress))`

I know that it is not allowed ,otherwise everyone can just selfdestruct any contract ,right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`call` uses the `CALL` opcode, which in bytecode is `0xf1`. This opcode takes a couple parameters, `address` and `data` being two of them. The data then is being forwarded to the target address and can be used by it, but itself doesn't invoke an opcode.

In your example `selfdestruct(address payable)` would be used to calculate the function selector and try to call this function on the target contract. It is completely up to the target contract if it implements such a function and what the function actually does.

`selfdestruct` is a different opcode with the bytedcode `0xff`, which takes an address as a parameter.

This is all defined in the yellow paper page 30ff: https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf

Comment: doesn't that mean anyone can call selfdestruct in targeted contract ?

Comment: If a contract doesn't implement a function that triggers the selfdestruct opcode, then this is not possible.

Comment: Just abi encoding the function `selfdestruct(address payable)` does not trigger the selfdestruct opcode. You would have to implement a public Solidity function on your contract that then could trigger the opcode.